# Remote Connect to MySQL Database on Ubuntu 20.04 on AWS

Tags: mysql, amazon-ec2, remote-access

I'm trying to connect to my MySQL database remotely; I feel like I've tried literally everything except for something that feels basic and elusive.

I have my server up as per these instructions:

- https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-apache-mysql-php-lamp-stack-on-ubuntu-20-04
- https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-allow-remote-access-to-mysql

I've installed this AMI: https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/prodview-iftkyuwv2sjxi

I've also added security groups (and, yes, I know that SSH shouldn't be open to everyone, I'm just testing)

[image]

When I run `nc -vz {{MY EC2 IP}} 3306` in my local terminal, nothing happens
When I run `nc -vz {{MY EC2 IP}} 3306` my local terminal, I get `Connection to {{MY EC2 IP}} 80 port [tcp/http] succeeded!`

I've edited my MySQL configuration file via `sudo nano /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf:` and made the following changes,

`bind-address            = 0.0.0.0`

I've also run: `sudo ufw allow 3306` & tried toggle on/off `ufw` (but for some reason I feel like I remember that ufw isn't necessary on EC2.

When I run `sudo systemctl status mysql`, I get:

```
 mysql.service - MySQL Community Server
      Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
      Active: active (running) since Wed 2023-02-08 18:41:08 UTC; 19min ago
```

When I run this it keeps blinking: `mysql -u {{user}} -h {{MY EC2 IP}}  -p`

What am i doing wrong? What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Welp, turns out it was 'simple' I just had the wrong security group applied to my instance.

Probably just goes to show that having nice, tidy, & clear Security Group names + cleaning up old ones can save a ton of time.